# How do I use CSS to reposition this image?

Tags: asp.net, css

In this image you see two versions of the same elements.  The top one is what I am getting, the bottom is what I want to end up with.  Of course the bottom of the image is lined up with the text in the label and the text in the textbox, but I need it lined up with the textbox's box.  I'm somewhat newbie at CSS, and the things I've tried so far do not get me even off the plate.

[image]

The controls are coded as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="TimeTextRequiredLabel" runat="server" Text="*"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="TimeTextLabel" runat="server" Text="Time:&nbsp;"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TimeTextBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" Width="100"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="TimePickerImageButton" runat="server" BorderWidth="0"
     Width="34" Height="21"  CssClass="TimePickerImage"
    ImageUrl="~/UserControls/Images/ClockPicker.gif" 
    ToolTip="Pick a time." />
```

What should be in my CSS, in the class "TimePickerImage" to scootch it leftwise and down the few pixels necessary?

**Edited to Add:**

Ultimately went with @JuanMendes solution, and this class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .TimePickerImage {
        position: relative;
        top: .2em;
        right: .3em;
    } 
</style>
```

This snugs it in right exactly where I needed it.  Thanks!  Next task is to get serious with learning CSS.  Thus far I've been playing script-kiddie with it.

**Edited Further to Add:**

I've tried all the other variations proposed by both @MarcAudet and @JuanMendes and the above code works best.  I guess I don't care so much about comforming to some theoretical "ideal" as making the thing result in what I need.

Comment: What are these elements wrapped in? A div? Table cell?

Comment: The elements are wrapped in a div.

Comment: You're testing this on IE right?

Comment: It would be helpful to see your style sheet (or the relevant parts of it).

Comment: Yes, IE, and I haven't created the stylesheet for it, yet.  It is in fact an ASP.NET UserControl.

Comment: If this is the case, you have a lot of control in how the styling can be applied, which is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always cheat and position the image yourself fudging values until it lines up(if you can't find a nicer way) http://jsfiddle.net/vTCHW/

Tested in FF, IE 8/9 and Chrome

```
img {
    position: relative;
    top: .3em;
}
```

You mentioned that [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16179349/227299) is almost good enough. I think that is a better solution. You can make all three line up correctly by removing padding/margin from the input. http://jsfiddle.net/vTCHW/1/ Note that many people use a [CSS reset system](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) that would have taken care of the margins/paddings for you

```
img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

input {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
}
```

Comment: This is also a good trick to remember.  Would pixels be better choice of units?

Comment: @MarcAudet Using `em`s allows you to not have to change the pixel fudge factor if the font size changes. However `vertical-align` seems to do the trick?

Comment: @CyberHerbalist I've updated my answer to provide a better answer (like Marc's) but that aligns the bottom of the image too

Comment: Using a CSS reset is a very good idea... for a reference see http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain yourself so I can improve the answer, it should be clear from my explanation why this isn't ideal and that this is something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add or adjust the `vertical-align: bottom` declaration in `#TimePickerImageButton`

From your screenshots, it appears that the image is aligned with the baseline of the text line, the default behavior for an inline image.

`vertical-align` will take care of the vertical positioning.

To move the element to the left, try adjusting `margin-left`.  However, check the margin on the input field since it may have a margin, and also look for some white space between the input field and the image.

**Demo**

If you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent ex2">
    <label for="the-time">Time:</label>
    <input id="the-time" type="text">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x25">
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```
.ex2 img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

You will see the positioning that you want.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2PkUF/

**If you have tall lines...**

If you apply a larger value for `line-height: 4.0`, aligning elements to the bottom of the line box may look goofy.

You can also try `vertical-align: text-bottom` which should work.

See Example 3 in the demo.

Comment: Yes, the alignment is what I mentioned in the question.  That's pretty much baseline alignment.

Comment: I tried several variations on vertical-align, including "bottom", "-3px", and there was no effect.

Comment: Check your `line-height` value, you may have to set it to 2.0 or else you may not see the adjustment.

Comment: That's pretty slick, although it pulls the image noticeably lower than the border of the textbox.

Comment: Actually, you can align elements with the text-bottom and that gives better results depending on your font-size, see Example 3 in the demo.